# Different statements of the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In different books, but also websites, there are different expressions for the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. For example,

- $\Delta x \Delta p \ge h$ (from The Physics of Atoms and Quanta)
- $\Delta x \Delta p \ge \hbar/2$ or
- $\Delta x \Delta p \ge \hbar$ (Demtroder)

etc.

Which one of these notations is the correct one? Or, if they're all correct, could someone provide me with some examples or context where each of them is used?

Comment: of course if something is largher than h_bar it is also larger than h_bar/2

Comment: @annav yeah true, but since we are in quantum mechanics I think that even the smallest value is crucial for the calculations

Comment: @Chair thanks for editing, I'm new here and I still did not learn how to correctly write formulas and stuff

Comment: I  voted for the duplicate above.

Comment: @anna v. Making this question a duplicate is an example of the situation I am blaming in my answer to the meta post  <a href="https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10898/is-the-demise-of-stack-exchange-as-we-know-it-ineluctable?cb=1">Is the demise of Stack Exchange (as we know it) ineluctable? </a>. I think that all the answers to the previous question have missed an important point. However, replying to a question of more than 2 yeas ago, will hardly be noticed, staring with the person who has asked the present question.

Comment: @GiorgioP According to you, which is the point that all the answers to this question have missed?

Comment: @GiorgioP I disagree. If the answers there have missed the point, people are invited to go to the other thread and answer: we will end up with all the good answers collected in one place. That is much better than the case where the good answers are spread across a bunch of different places.

Comment: @Chair: the spreading in a bunch of places is a technological limit of the platform. From the logical point of view, it would be enough to consider answers to the most recent question as continuation of the answers to the old one. I am used to think that logical needs should prevail on technological limits of the message organization. But this is matter for meta forum, I guess.

Comment: @physicist: what has missed in all the answers I have read is  that ,when speaking about Heisenberg uncertainty principle (today, not some decades ago), one should start clarifying which form of the so-called principle one is discussing. The historical "principle", even though it was such in the Heisenberg writings, it became a theorem of QM after Robertson, but this way it  moved from representing a limitation for a simultaneous measurement of two non-commuting observables to a statement about the product of the variance of the statistical distribution of such measurements. [to be continued]

Comment: @GiorgioP the second answer I think does the robertson or some such derivation with hermitian operators. The statistics part sounds confusing as it  is probabilities in quantum mechanics that are calculated. usually statistical distributions are thought as   poisson or gaussian .... It is the quantum mechanical solutions with the boundary conditions that control the probability, not random shots, no?

Comment: @physicist: [continuation] In the last copuple of decades some novel work has been done on the "Heisenberg principle" along a few independent directions. One of them was precisely to try to answer the question on what can be said on the limits for simultaneous measurements of non commuting observable in an individual measurement (as opposite to the statistical view of the classical formulation). Another direction was that taken by Maccone and Pati in a Phys. Rev. Lett. of 2014 (PRL 113,260401 (2014). It can be found on-line and its ref. 17,18 contain an updated list of refs. [to be continued].

Comment: @physicist: [cont.] Just to finish (writing in a sequence of comments is quite boring), the situation, today, is that people aware of such recent discussions start to distinguish between uncertainty "principle" and "relations". Moreover, the exact bound for $\Delta x \Delta p$, when interpreted as statement on an individual measurement has been matter of intense debate recently. Thus when discussing this topic, I would clarify which version of the uncertainty one is referring to, and while in the Robertson case there is no doubt about the factor $1/2$, in other cases I would use more caution.

Comment: @anna v: the second answer to the old question is a typical proof of the theorem. I do not see too much confusion. Maybe one could clarify that all the averages  are expectation values on a quantum state. In a Schrödinger representation, averages with a probability density given by $| \psi |^2$.